# Pass list of options to Plot3D

Tags: plotting, options

Consider the example

```
plotOptions = {PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2}

Plot3D[x y , {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, plotOptions]
```

Why does this causes the error:

```
Plot3D::nonopt: Options expected (instead of plotOptions) beyond position 3 in 
Plot3D[x y,{x,0,10},{y,0,10},plotOptions]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>
```

?

I would say that `plotOptions` *is* as list of rules...

If I use

```
Plot3D[x y , {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2}]
```

it works:

[image]

What is then the correct way of passing a list of options to a plot? One situation on when this happens is when I want to create several plots with the same options.

Comment: Try `Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},Evaluate@plotOptions]` its because of the `HoldAll` attribute of Plot functions!

Comment: Pff, it works! why is that? Can you provide an answer and respective explanation please?

Comment: The answer is that Plot3D has `HoldAll` attribute. I'll let @PlatoManiac post the answer.

Comment: This is a good candidate for an FAQ. It's something novices can all too easily be mystified by, before they know anything about `Hold`, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lets see the `Attributes` of `Plot3D`

```
Attributes[Plot3D]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

The `HoldAll` is the reason why your `options` are not read within the `Plot3D` command. In such situations (e.g NIntegrate, Plot,..) to resolve the values of a symbol (here `options`) within these commands we tend to use `Evaluate` to forcefully override this attribute.

So one solution is

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},Evaluate@plotOptions]
```

Another solution is to inject the options using `With`:

```
With[{iPlotOpts = plotOptions},
 Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, iPlotOpts]
]
```

Another way will be to get rid of this `HoldAll` globally using `ClearAttributes[Plot3D, HoldAll]`. Then you can just use `Plot3D[x y , {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, plotOptions]`. But clearing attributes globally is a **bad idea in general**, as it disrupts the local scoping which is often a must for a function like `Plot3D` to work seamlessly! 
Try for example:

```
ClearAttributes[Plot3D, HoldAll]; x = 5; y = 10; 
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: The last paragraph is **extremely bad advice**! Try for example: `ClearAttributes[Plot3D, HoldAll];
x = 5; y = 10;
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]`. Another solution is to inject the plot options using `With`

Comment: @Ajasja While I was editing the answer the site became inaccessible (at least in Germany)! At that time I was just mentioning the bad side effect of `ClearAttribute`. Now I am back from lunch and did finish the editing ;)

Comment: I emphasised your warning just in case:)

Comment: Thanx @Ajasja...

Answer (score 9):

There are other easy ways to inject the evaluated `plotOptions` into `Plot3D`. One very simple way is to use `With`. Here, the fundamental difference between `With` and `Module` comes to light: `With` does not localize variables. It assigns values to names and you can refer to your values by using the names:

```
With[{plotOptions = {PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2}},
 Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, plotOptions]
]
```

Another way is to make a function from your `Plot3D` call and pass your options as parameters

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, #] &[{PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2}]
```

In this way, you can of course remove the list braces

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ##] &[PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment on halirutan's answer, so this will have to suffice: the problem with his last suggestion is that

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, #] &[PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

is equivalent to

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, PlotPoints -> 10]
```

i.e., only the first option setting is inserted. The proper way to go about it is to use `SlotSequence` (`##`) instead; to wit,

```
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ##] &[PlotPoints -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

and both options shall then be inserted.

If you have an entire pile of options to insert, you could do something like

```
optList = {ColorFunction -> Hue, MaxRecursion -> 2, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 10};
Plot3D[x y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, ##] & @@ optList
```

Comment: The first half of this answer would have been better as a comment (or edit) to halirutan's answer.  I made the bug-fix edit myself.  However, +1 for the final line of code as that is a valuable method.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that may be useful for some is to use the optional arguments type of function. This allows you to set up a base style and then modify it when you use it without entering all the arguments.

This sets up a bunch of named options (in this case mainly duplicates of the normal plot options) and their default values:

```
imagesize = 300;;

Options[plot2dF] = {PlotRange -> All,
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> None,
  FrameTicks -> Automatic,
  PlotStyle -> Automatic,
  PlotLegends -> None,
  ImageSize -> imagesize};
```

This then creates a function that returns a list of options:

```
plot2dF[OptionsPattern[]] :=
  {PlotRange -> OptionValue[PlotRange],
   Axes -> OptionValue[Axes],
   Frame -> OptionValue[Frame],
   FrameLabel -> OptionValue[FrameLabel],
   FrameTicks -> OptionValue[FrameTicks],
   PlotStyle -> OptionValue[PlotStyle],
   PlotLegends -> OptionValue[PlotLegends],
   ImageSize -> OptionValue[ImageSize]};
```

Which can then be used with evaluate as described in the other answers:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Evaluate[plot2dF[PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]]]
```

[image: Code output]

The effect of this approach is very similar to just changing the default settings but it can be used in multiple plot scenarios (listplot, logpot etc) and you could have different versions of your function for different base settings.