# Handling options in my function

Tags: plotting, function-construction, options

It seems this should be easy, by I just can not figure out how. I'm making many very similar style plots, so I want to make a function with all the default options specified. Sometimes I need to tweak a plot though, like changing a color or adding a legend, so I want to be able to pass options to it if I want. If a want to tweak the plot the following function works

```
fplot[f_, range_, opt_] := 
  Plot[f, range, PlotLabel -> "A plot", Frame -> True, Axes -> False, opt];

fplot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {PlotStyle -> Orange,    
  FrameLabel -> {{"y[x]", ""}, {"x", ""}}}]
```

But I also want my function to be able to handle me not giving it options, so I want the following to work as well

```
fplot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

which now just gives me back the output:fplot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 [Pi]}]

I have loot at similar questions of passing optional options to a function, but I can't get either method to work, and they seem the require that I predefine the Options that I might later want to tweak. I would like to be able to tweak any of the options in Plot without having to predefine them.
[Passing list of options to Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29503/passing-list-of-options-to-plot)

[Pass list of options to Plot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/pass-list-of-options-to-plot3d)

Any help is much apprechiated!

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate as the solution you Accepted is already addressed therein.  However I encourage you to read through [(353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121) as I feel the approach you have chosen is not as efficient as it might be.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have editede it now. The If stuff was my attempt to create something, but it was a lot more complicated than what JasonB suggested further down in his post. That was the part of his answer that I ended up using. Is it still a duplicate?

Comment: In my opinion, yes, but a duplicate of [(353)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/121) instead.  I'll change the redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you evaluate the statement `opt=="def"` it evaluates to `True` if `opt` really is `"def"`, but it doesn't give `False` for any other object.

Read the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5286916/4712538) to see why you need to use `SameQ` (`===`) instead of `Equal` (`==`),

```
f[a_, opt_] := Module[{defOpt, opt2},
  defOpt = {PlotLabel -> "Label"};
  If[opt === "def", opt2 = defOpt, opt2 = Join[defOpt, opt]];
  Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Evaluate@opt2]]
```

[image]

For the record, the easiest way to define the function you have there is

```
f[a_, opt : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
  Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 π}, opt, PlotLabel -> "Label"]
```

and then

```
f[2]
f[2, Background -> LightBlue, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

would give the exact same output as above

Comment: how it helps with the second statement that gives false?

Comment: @garej, the way the OP's function was originally defined, it evaluates `opt` to see if it is `"def"`.  If that is `True` then it defines `opt2` in a certain way.  If it were `False` then it defines it a different way.  But the way he had it written, it was not evaluating to `False`

Comment: @JasonB, Thanks, that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

To define a function with options, give it a set of defaults and use `OptionsPattern` in the definition. To use the value of a particular option in the function defintion, use `OptionValue`:

```
Options[f] = {"ThisIsAnOption" -> False, SoIsThis -> 1};

f[a_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 (If[OptionValue["ThisIsAnOption"], Print[{opt}]]; a + OptionValue[SoIsThis])
```

If `f` is used without specifying any options, `OptionValue` will use the default values:

```
f[2]

(* 3 *)
```

If you specify an option where `OptionsPattern[]` is used in the definition, you can override the default values:

```
f[2, "ThisIsAnOption" -> True]

(* {"ThisIsAnOption"->True} *)
(* 3 *)
```

You can just add more options as you like and the order of the option arguments doesn't matter, so long as they all occur in sequence where `OptionsPattern[]` was specified:

```
f[2, SoIsThis -> 2, "ThisIsAnOption" -> True]

(* {SoIsThis->2, "ThisIsAnOption"->True} *)
(* 4 *)
```

This will trigger a message because `"NotValidOption` was never given for `Options[f]`:

```
f[2, "NotValidOption" -> "hello"]

(* OptionValue::nodef: Unknown option NotValidOption for f. *)
(* 3 *)
```

For your specific example, you can set the options of `f` to have the same options as `Plot` and override the default for `PlotLabel` with `SetOptions`. Then it's just a matter of passing the options argument to `Plot`. Here I used `Join` because it will take the first option value it finds if there are any duplicates:

```
Options[f] = Options[Plot];
SetOptions[f, PlotLabel -> "Label"];

f[a_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Plot[Sin[a x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Evaluate[Join[{opts}, Options[f]]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer :)